# Unable to override varargs method in scala?

Tags: scala

Given the following base class and one of its methods:

```
abstract class ServiceIf(val name: String) {


   def run(args: Any*):  Any = {}
```

An attempted subclass implementation is:

```
class RexecIf extends ServiceIf("Rexec") {

   override def run(execParams: ExecParams, nLoops: Int) = {
```

However the "varargs" does not work:

[image]

Is this expected behavior - that is that `varargs` should/may not be used for base class methods?

**Update**  I did not mention originally: a goal is to use the method within reflection for configuration file driven workflows. So using types-based approaches (as in the first answer) may be practical in some use cases but not in mine.

Comment: The compiler thinks you're trying to overload the `run` method because the profile of the 1st, `Seq[Any]=>Any`, doesn't match the profile of the 2nd, `(ExecParams,Int)=>??`.

Comment: Yea fair enough.  I just replaced the `varargs` with a `Seq`

Comment: Do you ever call the `run` method by normal means, without reflection? What's that usage like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overridden method has to be able to be called with any arguments the original accepted, not just the two you've provided. That is, a call `recexif.run(1, 2, 3)` has to be valid.

Also consider:

```
abstract class Base {
  def run(arg: Any) = {}
}

class Derived extends Base {
  override def run(arg: Int) = {}
}
```

This is similarly wrong, because the "override" does not implement the contract of the base method.

If you want the different implementations to accept different parameters for `run`, consider introducing an associated type or a type parameter. For example:

```
abstract class ServiceIf[RunArgs](val name: String) {
  def run(arg: RunArgs): Any = {}
}

class RexecIf extends ServiceIf[(ExecParams, Int)]("Rexec") {
  override def run(arg: (ExecParams, Int)) = {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: This can be useful probably for some folks - but I updated the question to show that not so much for mine. I will upvote anyways but have a  more suitable workaround.

Comment: I'm going to accept this - not because it's really what I was looking for but to close this up.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot override a general method with a more specific method. The override method must accept all the arguments that are accepted by the base method. So the code in the question can never be made to work.

You can, of course, have the override method fail unless it gets the values that it needs. Here is an example of how this works in this case:

```
abstract class ServiceIf(val name: String) {
   def run(args: Any*): Any = {}
}

class RexecIf extends ServiceIf("Rexec") {
  override def run(args: Any*) = {
    val Seq(execParams: ExecParams, nLoops: Int) = args
  }
}
```

This will fail with `MatchError` if the `args` do not match the pattern in the override method.

Answer (score -1):

While this is not an "answer" it is maybe the closest workaround - to use a `Seq` explicitly instead of the `varargs` ?

```
abstract class ServiceIf(val name: String) {

   def run(args: Seq[Any]):  Any = {}


class RexecIf extends ServiceIf("Rexec") {

   override def run(args: Seq[Any]) = {
     val Seq(execParams: ExecParams, nLoops: Int) = args
```

I will go ahead with the above approach unless a  more definitive answer appears - and would  still receive its proper due.

Comment: You do not need to change the type to `Seq[Any]`, you can just use `Any*` as before.

Comment: If that were working then it would have been used: the original version did not compile.

Comment: The original vesion did not compile because `execParams: ExecParams, nLoops: Int` is not compatible with `Arg*`. The problem is not the use of `Arg*` in the abstract method, it is the incompatible types in the override method.

Comment: Well then `Seq` is working well for my particular needs.